# Pop OS 22.04 - Brightness control not working on Acer Nitro 5

Tags: pop-os, brightness

Brightness control is not working on my new Acer Nitro 5 (Model: AN515-58-59JP, 12th Gen Intel Core i5 12450H, Nvidia 3050) after installing Pop OS 22.04; Nvidia proprietary drivers are installed (535).

Output of some of the commands (Pop OS 22.04):

`uname -r`

**Output:** 6.5.6-76060506-generic

`lspci | grep VGA`

**Output:** 0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P GT1 [UHD Graphics] (rev 0c) 0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] (rev a1)

`ls /sys/class/backlight/`

**Output:** nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight

Also, I am able to control brightness with `xrandr`. But, it often gets reset to full brightness again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing the same issue